# Tree Data: Possible to use a Column Group Definition as autoGroupColumnDef

Tags: ag-grid

I tried to use a column group as autoGroupColumnDef as I want the the header to be in the top row aligned with other top headers. When I do this the header is rendered in the "sub header" row and the innerRenderer is not used. Anyone knows if it's possible to get this to work?

The column group looks like this.

```
            headerName: 'Group header',
            children: [{
                headerName: '',
                suppressMovable: true,
                suppressSizeToFit: true,
                pinned: 'left',
                field: 'name',
                minWidth: 200,
                sort: 'asc',
                cellRendererParams: {
                    suppressCount: true,
                    innerRenderer: 'myCustomRenderer',
                }
            }]
        } as ColGroupDef
```

Comment: Reproduce your issue on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you easily.

Comment: Here is a plunker based on ag-grids tree data example. What I want is the "Organisation Hierarchy"-header in the top row.

https://plnkr.co/edit/93IY1HJdiqc0k8IH3rx9?p=preview